# My boss has asked me make a device which is capable of scanning rooms for bugs!

Tags: wireless, detection

Well this as I searched on the net is advertising, making money and fools out of those who want to make/buy such a bug scanner.

- I am not an electronics engineer but am being forced to.
- I do have access to all the hardware I may need.
- There are lots of shops claiming that they have devices which can scan a area to see if there are bugs or spy listener devices installed, but how do I know if these work?
- Personally I think this type of device only exists in James Bond movies :))

### My boss's reason

- He seems to hear some sound in the conference room, and his room where he has to stay for another month.
- He claims the sound is something like "tii-eee, tii, teee ti ti" and so on. lol

### Deliver

Okay, so now I have to reply to him with a gadget to scan his rooms for potential wireless transmitter bugs.

Comment: please refer this link also:  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9861/cannot-i-use-a-radio-receiver-type-deivce-built-in-cassete-players-to-scan-for-r

Comment: I think it may be time to start looking for a new boss.

Comment: Turn off fluorescent bulbs (& ballasts). Check for sound. ???. Profit.

Comment: haha, I thought this was actually referring to real bugs, not eavesdropping bugs.

Comment: It's worth noting that there is **NO** way to reliably detect passive (e.g. recording) bugs, short of a exhaustive physical search. All the answers so far deal *exclusively* with detecting bugs which **transmit** the audio they pick-up. Something which simply records to a SD card or similar for later retrieval it pretty much impossible to passively detect, (except when someone comes to retrieve it, anyways).

Comment: Furthermore, if you want to get really cutting edge, a modern FHSS (Frequency-hopping spread spectrum) device is very hard to detect even with a spectrum analyzer, provided the transmit duty cycle is kept low.

Answer (score 6):

Consider a new job. :)

Apart from that, you could try and rent a spectrum analyzer from an equipment rental service, build a simple loop antenna (cut the end off a coax cable, loop some wire from the center conductor to the ground braid) and 'sniff' around the room to see if there's any spurious RF transmissions coincident with the "tii-ee, tii, teee ti ti" noises.

Comment: Here's a cheap spectrum analyser for sub-1ghz http://ossmann.blogspot.com/2010/03/16-pocket-spectrum-analyzer.html

Comment: please rfer this link also:  thns

Answer (score 6):

You can detect some "bugs" which use radio waves to transmit sound (e.g. speech) to a remote listener or recorder. There are devices that cotain radio receivers which can detect a nearby radio transmitter - if the bug uses a radio-frequency in the range detectable by the detector.

It seems unlikely that a properly functioning bug of this sort would emit a noise your boss can hear. Check for faulty "wall-wart" power supplies and other electrical devices. You might have one of [these](http://www.thinkgeek.com/gadgets/electronic/b278/) :-)

In your shoes I'd get the boss to sign a purchase requisition for a commercial bug detector. I'd suggest to him that if he considers it important enough he allocate you a budget for hiring a security consultant. I'd also get him to purchase some bugs that could be used to test the effectiveness of the bug-detector.

If he insists you build a detector yourself, I'd first look for self-construction kits and equipment you can get him to pay for. Maybe he'll pay for training? You can find circuit examples from Google, for example the Talking Electronics' [kit](http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/BugDetector%28mini%29/BugDetector%28mini%29-P1.html) or an old Popular Electronics' [article](http://www.sentex.ca/~mec1995/circ/BugDetec/BugDetec.html) - I've no idea if these are any good but looking at a selection of these might give you an idea where to start.

If you are very unhappy with this, you will have considered looking for employment elsewhere. In the short term I'd try to look at it as an opportunity to gain experience and/or to demonstrate competence that could later be used (e.g. in an annual-review) to influence promotion or advancement.

Comment: you guidelines are right but i am happy, its just another task, but please provide some links to circuit diagrams, site with walk throughs

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a couple of examples of the sort of circuit I would attempt to build as a hobbyist.

Comment: +1 for the commercial bug detector and security consultant.

Answer (score 3):

Get a quote for renting a proper spectrum analyzer for a month.  It probably won't accomplish anything since there's likely nothing there to find, but they are quite fun to play with.  And useful to know about - you might really need one at some point in the future, and knowing your way around test equipment is always good, so make lemons out of lemonade and further your professional experience.

Given the cost of such equipment, rental is extremely common amongst even primary users.  There are of course cheap, limited devices out there, but it's good to know about the traditional instrument.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should build a dummy device, that actually detects a mobile signal, [such as this project](http://www.electroniq.net/radio-frequency/cell-phone-detector-circuit-diagram.html).

You can then show it to your boss, and test it with a mobile phone to prove it works, and tell him it will also work with eavesdropping bugs... Who knows, it might actually work!

Comment: The fact that this might actually happen scares me.

Answer (score 0):

Think geek [wi-spy spectrum analyzer](http://www.thinkgeek.com/gadgets/electronic/c240/)?  Will only do around 2.4GHz (the $300 version says it covers [2.400 - 2.4835 GHz](http://www.thinkgeek.com/gadgets/electronic/9558/)), but it will find obvious things (cell phones/wifi devices).  Since he's probably delusional (or legitimately paranoid due to breaking the law), its worth the $90 shot.  Or buy a proper spectrum analyzer for a couple thousand dollars.